# Pass a function as a parameter. C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I know this question may have been repeated many times, but I didn't understand their answers. So here we go:

I have an array of type `double*` and it is passed as a pointer named `arr` and the size of the array is passed as `int arrsize` parameter. Now, here is where I get confused, I want to perform the operation that is specified by the function pointer `typeOfOper` on the elements within the array using the parameter `val`.

```cpp
void fnOper(double *arr, int arrsize, void (*typeOfOper)(double*, int, const double), const double val);
```

I have four other functions that perform different types of operations (`add`, `subtract`, `divide`, `multiply`). So again, depending on the passed type of operation (`typeOfOper`), the function would execute one of the four other functions.

I would appreciate if someone can guide me and let me know what can I do. Thank you for your time.

Comment: not clear what's the snag here? I  see no real problem, you just call the function given? Start with one function to build an example

Comment: just type the name of the function in arguments without paranthesis when you call `fnOper`.

Comment: I'm trying to learn how to pass a function as a parameter so this is the easiest way I can do it for myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of the usage with your example. I may call the function `fnOper` with a pointer to the local function `operSum` or `operSubstract` like the following :

```cpp
    // call with sum
    fnOper(arrList, arrListSize, operSum, 15.3);
```

```cpp
    // call with substract
    fnOper(arrList, arrListSize, operSubstract, 15.3);
```

Here is the full compiling example :

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void operSubstract(double* a, int sizeOfa, const double z) {
    for (int i=0; i<sizeOfa; i++)
    {
        std::cout << std::fixed << *(a+i) << " MINUS ";
    }
    std::cout << z;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void operSum(double* a, int sizeOfa, const double z) {

    for (int i=0; i<sizeOfa; i++)
    {
        std::cout << std::fixed << *(a+i) << " PLUS ";
    }
    std::cout << z;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void fnOper(double *arr, int arrsize, void (*typeOfOper)(double* x, int y, const double z), const double val)
{
    (*typeOfOper)(arr, arrsize, val);
}

int main()
{
    // to display only 2 floating points to be good looking
    std::cout.precision(2);

    // preparation of actual arguments to use the functions with
    double arrList[] = {25.3, 15.2, 3.6};


    int arrListSize = sizeof(arrList)/sizeof(double);
    // call with sum
    fnOper(arrList, arrListSize, operSum, 15.3);

    // call with substract
    fnOper(arrList, arrListSize, operSubstract, 15.3);

}
```

The result looks like this :

```sh
25.30 PLUS 15.20 PLUS 3.60 PLUS 15.30
25.30 MINUS 15.20 MINUS 3.60 MINUS 15.30
```

Comment: Omg, I'm such an idiot. I honestly, couldn't wrap my head around it for some reason. Looked so stupid but thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

We often can use `std::function<void(double*, size_t)>` to hold functions and function-like objects. The big advantage is that you don't need a separate `const double val` anymore.

```
void fnOper(double *arr, size_t len, std::function<void(double*, size_t)> fun)
{
  fun(arr, len); // Simple
}

template <size_t LEN>
void fnOper(double (&arr)[LEN], std::function<void(double*, size_t)> fun)
{
  fun(arr, LEN); // Can also work on arrays
}
void add5 (double* ptr, size_t len) { 
   for (size_t i = 0; i != len; ++i) ptr[i] += 5.0;
}
double d[] = { 2.0,3.0,4.0 }
fnOper(d, add5)
```

But we'd typically not write code like this - there's already `std::transform` when we want to loop over an array, vector or list.